# Why can't I use `const MaterialApp` when using named routes?

Tags: flutter

I'm copying the named routes navigation documentation here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes.

My code is:

```dart
var app = const MaterialApp
    (
        title: 'o',     
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes:
        {
            '/': (context) => const SignInScreen(),
            '/journal': (context) => const JournalScreen(),
        },
    );
```

and an empty screen like:

```dart
class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget
{
    const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        return Scaffold
        ...
```

And the `routes` section gives me the error below. How can I fix it please?

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/data/journal/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "const_eval_throws_exception",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 12,
    "endLineNumber": 17,
    "endColumn": 3
},{
    "resource": "/c:/data/journal/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "const_constructor_param_type_mismatch",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/diagnostics/const_constructor_param_type_mismatch",
            "path": "/diagnostics/const_constructor_param_type_mismatch",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)>' in a const constructor.\nTry using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 12,
    "startColumn": 3,
    "endLineNumber": 16,
    "endColumn": 4
},{
    "resource": "/c:/data/journal/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "invalid_constant",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Invalid constant value.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 14,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 14,
    "endColumn": 42
},{
    "resource": "/c:/data/journal/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "non_constant_map_value",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/diagnostics/non_constant_map_value",
            "path": "/diagnostics/non_constant_map_value",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The values in a const map literal must be constant.\nTry removing the keyword 'const' from the map literal.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 14,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 14,
    "endColumn": 42
},{
    "resource": "/c:/data/journal/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "invalid_constant",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Invalid constant value.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 15,
    "startColumn": 16,
    "endLineNumber": 15,
    "endColumn": 50
},{
    "resource": "/c:/data/journal/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "non_constant_map_value",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://dart.dev/diagnostics/non_constant_map_value",
            "path": "/diagnostics/non_constant_map_value",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "dart.dev"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The values in a const map literal must be constant.\nTry removing the keyword 'const' from the map literal.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 15,
    "startColumn": 16,
    "endLineNumber": 15,
    "endColumn": 50
}]
```

Comment: Ok, it compiles if I remove the `const` from `var app = const MaterialApp`, but I don't understand why, and I want everything to be constant anyway.

Comment: If you are using const, you can't use dynamic variable for any parameter. In materialapp widget, route parameter takes some dynamic variable. That is why you should remove const if you using routes in material pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous functions can't be `const`. You can make them named functions and the code will compile. Like:

```dart
class Routes
{
  static Widget signinRoute(BuildContext context) => const SignInScreen();
}
```

```
routes:
        {
            '/': Routes.signinRoute,
```